# Objective C and c++ import problem. Simple but I don't get it

Tags: iphone, c++, class, objective-c++, box2d

I'm using cocos2d and box2d.(iPhone SDK) If I want to import box2d I add this to the top of the file **#import "Box2D.h"** and then I rename my class to "**.mm**". Now I have just a class *without* a ".m" file just a ".h" file.

It looks like that and if I import box2d it gives me many errors because box2d is c++ and normally i need to change it to ".mm" but i cant.

```
#import "Box2D.h"

// Defines individual types of messages that can be sent over the network. One type per packet.
typedef enum
{
    kPacketTypeTime = 1,
    kPacketTypePosition = 2,
    kPacketTypeStartSignal = 3,
} EPacketTypes;

// Note: EPacketType type; must always be the first entry of every Packet struct
// The receiver will first assume the received data to be of type SBasePacket, so it can identify the actual packet by type.
typedef struct
{
    EPacketTypes type;
} SBasePacket;

// the packet for transmitting a score variable
typedef struct
{
    EPacketTypes type;

    float time;
} STimePacket;

// packet to transmit a position
typedef struct
{
    EPacketTypes type;

    b2Vec2 position; //*******************************important**
    float rotation;

} SPositionPacket;

// packet to transmit a start signal
typedef struct
{
    EPacketTypes type;

    BOOL startGame;

} SStartSignalPacket;
```

Why I want to do this? Look at the "******important" in my code. I want to use b2Vec2.

Thank you very much for reading.
Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rename header to .hh, cause compiler still treats it as Objective C

Comment: at my important line i get this error : "Expected specifier qualifier list before "b2Vec". It still gives me 300+ errors. I had that problem in other classes too and a rename from .m to .mm solved the problem but here the .hh doesn't solves it. Should I mayby use #include

Comment: The easiest way then would be going yo project settings and there set 'Compile Sources As'   to  Objective-C++

Comment: sry my mistake. i missed something. your solution worked. thanks